# How can I paste table excluding blanks generated by ""

Tags: excel

I used formula in excel but it generates a lot "blank" cells by "" in the formula. These cells are not considered as blank (isblank returns false). How can I delete all these "blanks" or how can I copy paste my table without the ""s. I can't use filter as the table is more complex. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 'fake' blanks with anything that can safely then be replaced with nothing (true blank) then Go To Special Blanks and delete.